# Mempool management

Tags: mempool

What are the considerations that came into play when choosing the design of the Tezos mempool management ?

Arthur has made a number of remarks on that topic in some video dev updates but I would like to get more details in written form if possible that could become part of the community wiki ?

Answer (score 4):

I think that, currently, the choice of the operations included in a block is done to maximize fees-per-gas for transactions and originations, while all other operations (endorsements, votes, etc.) are always included. Anyway, a choice is only done if there are too many operations for a block, we are not in this situation right now.